# Am I missing something with this question about nested compact sets?

Tags: general-topology

On my homework, I have a question that states:

Let $X$ be a compact space, and suppose $\{ F_n \}$ is a countable collection of nonempty closed subsets of $X$ that are nested. Show that $\cap_n F_n$ is nonempty.

It seems trivial since the finite intersection, $\cap_{k=1}^n F_k$, is just $F_n$, which is nonempty.

Comment: It is trivial. @MartinCitoler 0.

Comment: @MartinCitoler I updated the question so there is no confusion. I was confused with the notation and thought that it was asking if the finite intersections of nested nonempty compact sets is a nonempty set.

Comment: Bill you are absolutely right. I don't know what I was thinking.. I am going to delete the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the notation means; by definition,

$$\bigcap_n F_n = F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3 \cap ...$$

and in general, might not be equal to *any* of the $F_n$'s.

---

The notation used here is slightly ambiguous, and it's much better to write something like

$$\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$$ or $$\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty}$$

Comment: Thanks, I though it was asking about a finite intersection.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* Now that things are clear, consider the open sets $O_n=X\smallsetminus F_n$.

Comment: No fun. I was only confused about the notation.

Comment: @user1876508 And... that's why you downvoted? It isn't really clear that was the *only* question.

Comment: It was not relevant to what I was asking. It's like spoiling a story by hinting what will happen at the climax of the plot.

Comment: @user1876508 As I said, it wasn't really clear you were wondering about the notation *alone*. Try to use comments instead, since downvotes are misleading when wrongly given.